# How to display maths equations in README.md files on GitHub?

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages

I have created a simple [GitHub repository](https://github.com/aleksyprok/test_math). I would like the README.md to display equations using the latex syntax. I would like e.g. `$$E=mc^2$$` to display an equation as it does in Latex.

I have tried using [this plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mathjax-3-plugin-for-gith/peoghobgdhejhcmgoppjpjcidngdfkod), and this works for me. However, I would like the maths to be displayed for everyone, regardless of which browser or plugins they are using. Do you know a simple way to do this?

Comment: _Pictures_, basically.

Comment: It's a shame we have to do that because I nearly have what I want when I have with this plugin installed: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mathjax-3-plugin-for-gith/peoghobgdhejhcmgoppjpjcidngdfkod

Comment: Right, except that as you've realised then you have to make everybody else install it too!